# What is the default retention period for LogGroup in Cloud Watch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html) is documentation about creating Cloud Watch `LogGroup` via Cloud Formation. They said:

> RetentionInDays
>
> The number of days log events are kept in CloudWatch
>   Logs. When a log event expires, CloudWatch Logs automatically deletes
>   it. For valid values, see PutRetentionPolicy in the Amazon CloudWatch
>   Logs API Reference.
>
> Required: No

So if I create LogGroup without `RetentionInDays` parameter will Cloud Watch keep those logs forever? Or what `RetentionInDays` value they use by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, log data is stored in CloudWatch Logs indefinitely. However, you can configure how long to store log data in a log group. Any data older than the current retention setting is automatically deleted. You can change the log retention for each log group at any time.

Source :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#SettingLogRetention

Comment: The current working link is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#SettingLogRetention